# Snapchat-like Horizontal ScrollView Combined with React Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios, react-navigation-stack

I'm trying to create a `ScrollView` similar to Snapchat's frontend, with 3 screens. However, I want to be able to use `react-navigation`'s ability to set an initial route so that every time the home screen loads, it starts on the middle screen instead of the left-most screen.

This is for `react-native` version: `0.57.1`, and `react-navigation` version: `3.0.9`. This works fine when I put all 3 screens in the `ScrollView` component directly, but then I can't find a way to select which screen is displayed initially.

Here is something similar to what I'm aiming for:

```
const HomeScreenStack = createStackNavigator({
    Goals: GoalsScreen,
    Dash: DashScreen,
    Plans: PlansScreen,
}, {
    initialRouteName: "Dash"
})

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ScrollView
                horizontal={true}
                pagingEnabled={true}
                showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true}>
                <HomeScreenStack />
            </ScrollView>
        )
    }
}
```

I expect `HomeScreenStack` to display all 3 routes within a `ScrollView`, but I get an error saying:

```
Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation:
The navigation prop is missing for this navigator.
In react-navigation 3 you must set up your app container directly.
More info: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/app-containers.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using a `ScrollView`, you could take advantage of `react-navigation`'s [`createMaterialTopTabNavigator`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/material-top-tab-navigator.html) and nullify the `tabBarComponent`. It has swipe navigation enabled by default.

You also need to set up an [app container](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/app-containers.html) for `react-navigation`, which is where that error is coming from.
*Note that `AppContainer` should be used only once and in the main entry point file, such as `App.js`.*

```js
import { createAppContainer, createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation'

const HomeNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
  {
    Goals: GoalsScreen,
    Dash: DashScreen,
    Plans: PlansScreen,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Dash",
    tabBarComponent: null
  }
)

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(HomeNavigator)

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AppContainer />
    )
  }
}
```